# Using parameters in Angular app.routes.js resolve function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to jump in on an Angular project and have almost no experience with that, can someone help me how to add parameters to the app.routes.js?

I have this example:

```
.state('product-article', {
            resolve: {
                productArticleData: getProductArticleData
            },
            url: '/product-article',
            templateUrl: siteInfo.templateRoot + '/productArticlePage.html',
            controller: 'ProductArticlePageController',
            controllerAs: 'ProductArticlePageCtrl'
        })
```

further down in the same file I can find:

```
function getProductArticleData(ProductArticleApiService) {
    return ProductArticleApiService.getData();
}
```

and in the ProductArticleApiService.js I found this:

```
angular.module('ourApp').factory('ProductArticleApiService', ['apiBase','$http', ProductArticleApiService]);

function ProductArticleApiService(apiBase, $http) {
    return {
        getData: function() {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: apiBase + '/product_article/98',
                headers: {
                    'X-Siteaccess': 'eng'
                }
            });
        }
    };
};
```

Now it is my task to make this more dynamic, to replace the hardcoded "98" and 'eng' from the last file, so I added these parameters to the getData() function, added them also to the getProductArticleData function:

```
function getProductArticleData(ProductArticleApiService, article_id, siteaccess) {
    return ProductArticleApiService.getData(article_id, siteaccess);
}
```

But things go wrong when I am trying to do this in the app.routes.js:

```
resolve: {
                productArticleData: getProductArticleData("98","eng")
            },
```

(i know, still not dynamic, but I think this is the way to go) 
this is crashing my app. That makes sense, because I only give 2 parameters to a function that requires 3. BUT, before I made all those changes, it worked. How is it possible that the app worked at all with the original code? in the resolve: part I don't give the ProductArticleApiService as a parameter to the getProductArticleData function and yet it works, but when I add extra parameters it doesn't ?

Comment: When/where would the parameters actually be supplied? In the url?

Comment: as far as I understood the whole app.routes.js would be generated with all the parameters already in it.

Comment: Right now it's really difficult to tell what you're asking. "generating routes.js" doesn't make much sense in the context of Angular as there isn't a "code generation" step involved. can you please take another stab at explaining what you're trying to do?

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the above (why it doesnt work as expected) is `getProductArticleData` **isnt** actually treated like a normal function. It behaves more like the function seen in controllers where the parameters specified are actually going to be injected by angular:

```
angular.module("ourApp").controller(function ($scope, Service1, Service2) {
    // some code
});
```

So in your example, `ProductArticleApiService` is an angular service that will be injected and your app is probably broken because angular is now trying to inject `article_id` and `siteaccess` as services. Since (I assume) there are no such services it fails.

I suspect what you're trying to do is to alow the parameters for the `$http` request to be specified external to the service. So This might be what you're looking for:

```
.state('product-article', {
        resolve: {
            // I moved the function here for clarity
            // added $stateParams to be injected
            productArticleData: function (ProductArticleApiService, $stateParams) {
                return ProductArticleApiService.getData($stateParams.articleId, $stateParams.siteaccess);
            }
        },
        // changed url
        url: '/product-article/:articleId/:siteaccess',
        templateUrl: siteInfo.templateRoot + '/productArticlePage.html',
        controller: 'ProductArticlePageController',
        controllerAs: 'ProductArticlePageCtrl'
    })
```

A couple of things to note here:

- I changed the URL to accept two parameters `:articleId` and `siteaccess` and it can now be called as `/product-article/98/en`
- I changed the function to accept both `ProductArticleApiService` and `$sateParams`. `$stateParams` is a "service" that provides the url parameters from above.

I highly suggest you take a deep look at how routing in angular works, specifically [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) and [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) (they are related but different + you are using ui-router in your code).

Hopefully that should be enough to get you started. Comment for clarification on anything.

Comment: Thank you, this $stateParams helped a lot !